# When TCP SACK is already enabled, it is lost again

Tags: tcp

[image]

Because the No. 4245 packet loss, a new segment block is generated, but why the original 3040050-3048810 segment block will disappear.

Can anyone help me to explain this situation?

Comment: In the above figure, it is obvious that after the data sender loses the packet, the SACK sender also loses SACK the block [ 3040050-3048810 ]. But this picture shows that the SACK block [ 3040050-3048810 ] has been sent many times, but it happened to be lost after the data sender lost the packet. Is this coincidence?

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

According [RFC 2018](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2018) (ch.3):

*The SACK option is advisory, in that, while it notifies the data
sender that the data receiver has received the indicated segments,
the data receiver is permitted to later discard data which have been
reported in a SACK option.  A discussion appears below in Section 8
of the consequences of advisory SACK, in particular that the data
receiver may renege, or drop already SACKed data.*

The block [3040050-3048810] has been sent in packet 4244, so the SACK block sender deemed unnecessary to send it again.